# GUI for Django migrations

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-migrations

Is there a web solution to manage django migrations? I couldn't find any.

It's a pain to SSH and run `manage.py migrate` every time I want to migrate. It would be really nice if:

- at least a part of the migration mechanism was integrated to `django-admin`l
- there was a web-page with all the pending migrationsl
- you could run and rollback them;
- you could and see the corresponding logs if something goes wrong.

Comment: The Django admin relies on a working database, so it can not work properly while migrating.

Comment: But the database is perfectly accessible during migrations anyway?

Comment: It's a great idea for new package I think :)

Comment: I'm thinking, this could enable to build something like Airtable based on Django.